# How to filter for a object wiith a "value" and "name" in QBO api?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

It seems like the API won't permit a query filter of the form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM purchaseorder WHERE APAccountRef.value='33'
```

In the case of purchase orders, it seems to mean that I need to bring down every purchase order to my server and scan for the account I need which is highly suboptimal.  Is there some other syntax for querying against the many attributes which have been encoded like

```json
{
  "APAccountRef": {
    "value": "33",
    "name": "Accounts Payable (A/P)"
  }
}
```

with just a name and value attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [QuickBooks Documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/purchaseorder), it gives you a list of all fields and a list of fields that are `filterable`. Your query is using a field (`AccountRef.value='39'`) that *does not exist* as part of `PurchaseOrder`.

The correct field is:

> `APAccountRef`: ReferenceType
>
> Specifies to which AP account the bill is credited.

So your query should be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM purchaseorder WHERE APAccountRef = '39'
```

Comment: When I try APAccountRef='39' I get {"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Invalid query","Detail":"QueryValidationError: property 'APAccountRef' is not queryable","code":"4001"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2018-09-17T17:20:32.057-07:00"}

Comment: I also tried SELECT * FROM PURCHASEORDERS WHERE APAccountRef.value='39' and get QyereyValidationError Property APAccountRef.value not found for Entity PurchaseOrder"

Comment: I would report this to Intuit as a bug then. It should be a `filterable` field according to their documentation. You should be able to enter a support ticket from within your Intuit developer account.

Comment: This has been fixed in the api now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in python-

```
"select * from purchaseorder where APAccountRef in ('33')"
```